# Can I restrict Easy Search to only return published data?

Tags: security, search, meteor

I'm using matteodem's [Easy Search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search) package and have just discovered that instead of returning only published documents, the searches have access to the entire collection.

I've tested this by setting my publish function to return an empty array, and then checking that MyCollection.find().fetch() in the console correctly returns []. But searching MyCollection with Easy Search still returns all matching documents in the collection.

Is there any way to ensure that Easy Search only passes permitted data up to the client? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From matteodem, the developer of [Easy Search](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search), I have a simple answer to my original question of how to ensure that only published data are returned by a search.

The easiest way is to use a client-side search engine such as Minimongo. This accesses data through your publications, so will see exactly the data that you have published, no more no less. No selector is needed.

Example code:

```
postsIndex = new EasySearch.Index({
  collection: Posts,
  fields: ['name', 'tags', 'created_by_username'],
  defaultSearchOptions: {
    limit: 6
  },
  engine: new EasySearch.Minimongo() // search only on the client, so only published documents are returned
});
```

Alternatively you could use a server-side search engine such as MongoDB. In this case you should add a selector to control what data are returned.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to get selectors working with MongoDB. You can't use Meteor.userId() because the code runs on both server and client, and when I try the recipe for this in the documentation, I see an error on the server. Using Michel Floyd's construction, options.search.userId exists but is null. If I find out how to do it, I'll update this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

*Easy Search* is running the search on the server where it has universal access. According to the [docs](http://matteodem.github.io/meteor-easy-search/docs/core/) you can setup a *default selector* to filter the search by some criteria. In your case you can just copy the selector from your normal publication (the first parameter in your publication's `find()`) and set that as the default selector for *Easy Search*.

```
let index = new EasySearch.Index({
  collection: someCollection,
  fields: ['name'],
  engine: new EasySearch.Minimongo({
    sort: () => ['score'], // sort by score
    selector: function (searchObject, options, aggregation) {
      // selector contains the default mongo selector that Easy Search would use
      let selector = this.defaultConfiguration().selector(searchObject, options, aggregation);

      // modify the selector to only match documents created by the current user 
      selector.createdBy = this.userId || options.search.userId; // to run on both client and server
      return selector;
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Could you possibly show me an example? I have been looking at the docs for 2 days and just can't work out what to do, also the docs are out of date in many areas.

Comment: For example, how would you set it so that when searching posts, only posts created by the user were returned?

Comment: Thanks! In your example, should it be Meteor.userId() not Meteor,userId()?

Comment: The developer Matteodem has been very helpful answering questions. It seems that if you use the engine Minimongo, as in your example, then the search only runs on the client and will only return published data. I've tried this and it seems to work perfectly. You only need to use a selector if you are using MongoDB as the engine, because as you say that searches on the server.

Comment: You can't access Meteor.userId() from this function. According to EasySearch documentation, the userId is to be found in options.search.userId.

Comment: Thanks for that tip @Sebastien, I updated the answer accordingly.